# Gray view with a white horizontal bar appearing after Google signin from my Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-signin

My Android app uses Fragments and includes Google signin authorization via Firebase. After signing in and starting a Fragment transaction, the following appears, overlaying the Fragment underneath it:

[image]

It's as if the gray screen was a Dialog window. When I touch the screen, the gray view disappears:

[image]

Has anyone here seen this problem or know what's causing it?
It doesn't happen when the user signs in with an email address (passwordless), only with Google signin.

Comment: Nothing useful in the logs from Firebase / Google SDK when this happens ... ?